# How to detect a framed image from a photo in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, camera, photo

I'm wondering if there's a way to, after allowing a user to take a photograph, analyze the photograph and find a framed image within it. (For example, if someone took a photograph of a framed family portrait or something, I want to be able to programmatically sense the image and where the border of the portrait begins and work with the image).

Any help at all is really appreciated, I don't know much about graphics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This would take tons of coding. If you aren't very with graphics manipulation, then maybe you should do a little research on it. Unless there is an apple-provided shortcut that I don't know about...

Comment: Hmm. So might a better idea be to have the user trace around the image? Is there a good way to implement that?